# Convert 1D array into 2D, 3D array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

this is my array :

```
const array = [{
    "column": "9",
    "length": "1",
    "name": "10",
    "row": "3",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "0"
  },
  {
    "column": "1",
    "length": "1",
    "name": "2",
    "row": "3",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "0"
  },
  {

    "column": "3",
    "length": "1",
    "name": "4",
    "row": "3",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "0"
  },
  {

    "column": "5",
    "length": "1",
    "name": "6",
    "row": "3",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "0"
  },
  {

    "column": "7",
    "length": "1",
    "name": "8",
    "row": "3",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "0"
  },
  {
    "column": "6",
    "length": "2",
    "name": "U12",
    "row": "1",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "1"
  },
  {
    "column": "6",
    "length": "2",
    "name": "U11",
    "row": "2",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "1"
  },
  {
    "column": "8",
    "length": "2",
    "name": "U15",
    "row": "1",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "1"
  },
  {
    "column": "8",
    "length": "2",
    "name": "U14",
    "row": "2",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "1"
  },
  {
    "column": "0",
    "length": "2",
    "name": "U3",
    "row": "1",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "1"
  },
  {
    "column": "0",
    "length": "2",
    "name": "U2",
    "row": "2",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "1"
  },
  {
    "column": "2",
    "length": "2",
    "name": "U6",
    "row": "1",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "1"
  },
  {
    "column": "2",
    "length": "2",
    "name": "U5",
    "row": "2",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "1"
  },
  {
    "column": "4",
    "length": "2",
    "name": "U9",
    "row": "1",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "1"
  },
  {
    "column": "4",
    "length": "2",
    "name": "U8",
    "row": "2",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "1"
  },
  {
    "column": "8",
    "length": "2",
    "name": "L10",
    "row": "0",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "0"
  },
  {
    "column": "0",
    "length": "2",
    "name": "L2",
    "row": "0",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "0"
  },
  {
    "column": "0",
    "length": "2",
    "name": "L1",
    "row": "1",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "0"
  },
  {
    "column": "0",
    "length": "1",
    "name": "1",
    "row": "3",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "0"
  },
  {
    "column": "0",
    "length": "2",
    "name": "U1",
    "row": "4",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "1"
  },
  {
    "column": "2",
    "length": "2",
    "name": "L4",
    "row": "0",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "0"
  },
  {
    "column": "2",
    "length": "2",
    "name": "L3",
    "row": "1",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "0"
  },
  {
    "column": "2",
    "length": "1",
    "name": "3",
    "row": "3",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "0"
  },
  {
    "column": "2",
    "length": "2",
    "name": "U4",
    "row": "4",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "1"
  },
  {
    "column": "4",
    "length": "2",
    "name": "L6",
    "row": "0",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "0"
  },
  {
    "column": "4",
    "length": "2",
    "name": "L5",
    "row": "1",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "0"
  },
  {
    "column": "4",
    "length": "1",
    "name": "5",
    "row": "3",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "0"
  },
  {
    "column": "4",
    "length": "2",
    "name": "U7",
    "row": "4",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "1"
  },
  {
    "column": "6",
    "length": "2",
    "name": "L8",
    "row": "0",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "0"
  },
  {
    "column": "6",
    "length": "2",
    "name": "L7",
    "row": "1",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "0"
  },
  {
    "column": "6",
    "length": "1",
    "name": "7",
    "row": "3",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "0"
  },
  {
    "column": "6",
    "length": "2",
    "name": "U10",
    "row": "4",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "1"
  },
  {
    "column": "8",
    "length": "2",
    "name": "L9",
    "row": "1",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "0"
  },
  {
    "column": "8",
    "length": "1",
    "name": "9",
    "row": "3",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "0"
  },
  {
    "column": "8",
    "length": "2",
    "name": "U13",
    "row": "4",
    "width": "1",
    "zIndex": "1"
  }
]
```

I need to convert this array as follows 2d & 3d array as follows -

```
2dArray['row']['column'] //( 2d )

3dArray['zIndex']['row']['column']  //(3d )
```

I tried to use nested map, but am getting error and also am not sure its the efficient way of doing this !

Is this is the right way of handling or is there any other efficient way of doing this ? As, my purpose is to use this to create a table like matrix! need to place elements based on the row, columns and zIndex!

```
array.map(o => {
     o.map(e => {
       e.name
   })
})
```

Please guide !

Comment: Welcome to SO! I don't really understand what the 2d and 3d versions are supposed to look like. Can you show the expected output given this input, but maybe minimize it a bit to say, 3-4 elements, if that's enough to reproduce the logic? The elements are all numbers so `3dArray['zIndex']['row']['column']` seems rather nonsensical if I understand correctly--all 3 keys are terminal properties, not intermediate objects themselves so it's not clear to me how you'd index into a series of numbers like this. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure `row`, `column` pairs are unique? So are there any duplicated objects which has same `row` and `column`?

Comment: Yes row & columns are unique ! am damn sure

Comment: Consider this in html, how you will place elements based on row & column ? And additionally need to create two table and first table will contain array elements which has zIndex as 0 and second table contain zIndex as 1 ! just saying this for your example reference ! @ggorlen

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.reduce` is great for this kind of problem.

```js
const 3dArray = array.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (!acc[item.zIndex]) acc[item.zIndex] = [];
  if (!acc[item.zIndex][item.row]) acc[item.zIndex][item.row] = [];
  acc[item.zIndex][item.row][item.column] = item;
  return acc;
}, [])
```

Comment: how is this best from the above solution given by Nick ?

Comment: I'm not saying it's "best", I just think it's "great", because it's clear and terse.

Comment: Above code just show `3dArray` conversion. I can combine the two into one function, but you need to clarify how to resolve the conflict in `2dArray` when items overlap. I observe examples like: `{ zIndex: 0, row: 1, column: 0 }, { zIndex: 1, row: 1, column: 0 }`. You see these two have same row and column but different zIndex.

Comment: yes right, a group of array with zIndex 0 and another group with zIndex 1

Comment: eh, so you mean, you'll get two `2dArray` if you have `zIndex` = 0 and 1, is that correct?

Comment: Then it's just `const [2dArray0, 2dArray1] = 3dArray;`.

Comment: yes, i need 2d array when zIndex = 0 and 3darrya when zIndex is 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223279/discussion-between-nothingimp-and-hackape).

Comment: do check on the chat !